# Child Controls From Custom Control Null

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, custom-controls

I have a problem with a custom control in my Windows Modern App.


The control has a structure like a `Hub` Control: a main control with a list with child controls which can be defined in the xaml markup (like `HubSection`).


Everything works fine but in the page the child controls are null. The `InitializeComponent` method is generated correct together with the fields, but the fields from the child controls are always `null`.


You can reproduce it with these classes:

```
// The control with a list of child controls
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_Panel", Type = typeof(StackPanel))] 
public class MainControl : Control {
    public MainControl() {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MainControl);

        ChildControls = new List<UIElement>();
    }

    public List<UIElement> ChildControls { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate() {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        StackPanel panel = (StackPanel)GetTemplateChild("PART_Panel");

        foreach (UIElement uiElement in ChildControls) {
            panel.Children.Add(uiElement);
        }
    }
}
```

```xaml
<!-- The template for the control. -->
<Style TargetType="local:MainControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MainControl">
                <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Panel" Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```xaml
<!-- Using the control in a Page. -->
<controls:MainControl x:Name="mainControl">
    <controls:MainControl.ChildControls>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1" />
        <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button 2" />
        <Button x:Name="button3" Content="Button 3" />
    </controls:MainControl.ChildControls>
</controls:MainControl>
```

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    if (button1 == null) {
        Wait(); // Why is button1 generated but always null?
    }
}
```

I guess I need some attributes or register something in the constructor.

Comment: Because it is out of scope.

Comment: And is it possible to get it in scope? The `Hub` does so. I guess in the constructor since the `InitalizeComponent` just constructs the control and does not raise the Loaded Event or anything else.